# What is the best way to show only filtered records with empty columns from Sharepoint list inside gallery

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, sharepoint-list

The exact question is: how to display only filtered records in the gallery, filtered by condition that one of the columns is empty (has no value in it).

Let's imagine I have a Sharepoint list 'X', and I have many columns in it, and one of them is called 'C'. In PowerApps, I want to have a vertical gallery, which would only show the records from the list X that have the column C empty.

If I use the `IsBlank()` or other conditions I get delegation warning, what is the correct way to do it, or what is the workaround?

I even made a view of the Sharepoint list, but views apparently can't be used inside PowerApps.

Any pro tips?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that would be to have use Blank() and compare with the column C. E.g.

```
Filter(X, C = Blank())
```

Where X is your list and C your column

That is delegable and won't show you the warning message.

Note that this will work for '=' but not '<>'